# Faster way to run simulink simulation repeatedly for a large number of time

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I want to run a simulation which includes SimEvent blocks (thus only Normal option is available for sim run) for a large number of times, like at least 1000. When I use sim it compiles the program every time and I wonder if there is any other solution which just run the simulation repeatedly in a faster way. I disabled Rebuild option from Configuration Parameter and it does make it faster but still takes ages to run for around 100 times.

And single simulation time is not long at all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say why the model compiles every time without actually seeing the model and what's inside it. However, the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/parallel-computing/) provides you with the ability to distribute the iterations of your model across several cores, or even several machines (with the [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/distriben/)). See [Run Parallel Simulations](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/running-parallel-simulations.html) in the documentation for more details.

Comment: You might also be interested in this webinar: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/videos/speeding-up-simulink-applications-81795.html

Comment: yeah thats what i am looking into now. Thank your for your suggestion, I dont know if i can ask it here but is there any way to initialize simulation and run it again without stopping it? like clear up every entities and other variables in the system.